# C# Conditional lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, locking

I am writing performance critical code and thus want to minimize the calls to `lock(){ ... }`.
The critical part is a dictionary:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, System.Messaging.MessageQueue> _messageQueues;
```

When reading and adding from/to that dictionary at the same time, then there could be corrupt data. That is why I don't want to allow these two operations at the same time. 
**SOLUTION 1**

```
lock (_lock) {
   _messageQueues.Add(queueName, result);
}
```

and in another method:

```
lock(_lock){
   if (_messageQueues.TryGetValue(queueName, out result)) {
      return result;
   }
}
```

But I don't like that solution because now only one thread can read at a time. 
I'd like to allow multiple readers or none if writing is currently happening.

**SOLUTION 2**
Adding a boolean field:

```
private static volatile bool _currentlyModifying;
```

Writing to the dictionary like that:

```
try {
   _currentlyModifying = true;
   lock (_lock) {
      _messageQueues.Add(queueName, result);
   }
}
finally {
   _currentlyModifying = false;
}
```

and reading like that:

```
if (_currentlyModifying) {
   lock (_lock) {
      if (_messageQueues.TryGetValue(queueName, out result)) {
         return result;
      }
   }
} else {
   //Here is the new problem
   if (_messageQueues.TryGetValue(queueName, out result)) {
      return result;
   }
}
```

**QUESTION**
That would work pretty well, but there is a race condition:
One thread could start to write right after another thread has started to read.
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Why not use a `ConcurrentDictionary<T>` instead?

Comment: Look up at ConcurrentDictionary class of .Net- might help. Just not sure about how it handles which threads can read but I assume they have a good solution.

Comment: Another problem with Solution 2 (for *general* usage) is if there are multiple writers trying to access the lock. If they both reach `lock()` at the same time, one of them will get in, make changes, release the lock (the second writer can now get the lock) and *unsets* `_currentlyModifying` whilst the second writer is still inside the lock.

Comment: Basically, don't try to reinvent threading logic if you're not extremely aware of how races can appear and you have a specific need that isn't already addressed. As others have suggested, `ConcurrentDictionary` is the most obvious place to go to. Another alternative is to use [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300132(v=vs.110).aspx), which sounds like it has *exactly* the locking semantics you're asking for.

Comment: Instead of using locks and flag like `_currentlyModifying`, `ConcurrentDictionary<T>` might be better solution for you. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369(v=vs.110).aspx) is one example which uses threaded read-write in this dictionary.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Damn right, didn't thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx). If you dont have this available, then you can segment your code in to readers and writers (like CQRS on a small scale :) and use the [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.90).aspx) class to optimize performance.

Comment: Awesome I've had that problem a few times already. Great there is an out of the box solution :)